# Paypal's IPN in Wicket application

Tags: java, paypal, wicket, paypal-ipn

I am building Wicket based web application with Paypal's "Buy now" buttons implemented. The functionality I need is to allow users download the file only when the transaction was verified. What I don't really understand is how to implement the IPN in the Wicket application. Before start coding, i need to know the basic theory behind it.

So what would be the steps to verify the payment using Paypal's IPN in Wicket application? Could "Success" and "IPN callback" pages be the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPN is a callback from paypal to notify merchant about mixed types of changes. The IPN listerner (your page) has to implement its protocol described on
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Citation:
The action to take when your listener is notified of an event are application-specific. Here are some common actions applications take in response to IPN messages:

```
Trigger order fulfillment or enable media downloads
Update a list of customers
Update accounting records
Create specialized "to do" lists
```

---

*Success payment page* is a page there is client browser redirected after a successful payment.

The result is that *success payment page* is called once or none at a single payment depending on its result. The *IPN* listener can be call anytime, even though no payment is currently in process!

As shown on an image in the link, the IPN callback is destiny to process mixed background operations. E.g. store given results into your database, etc.

Comment: So IPN Listener page should receive IPN messages as page parameters?

Comment: Yes, the IPN uses HTTP POST data transfer and form encoding 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', so it is acceptable as PagePrameters in Wicket.

Comment: Thank you, Martin. And my final question: In general, what I don't really understand is how IPN Listener and Success Page are related. Let's say the payment was successful and the user was redirected to a Success Page. Should I check for stored IPN variables in my Success page? If not, where do I need to handle IPN messages?

Comment: There is more than a single payment confirmation notification defined on IPN listener. Also the notification to IPN has two phases, get the message, confirm the message back to PayPal and then receive the final result again. All of there are described on https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/ very well. See the image https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/ipn/IPN_auth_flow.gif

Comment: For example subscription and its revocation that is out of the scope of a single payment process. You can sign/confirm a monthly payment (e.g. sending business news). There is paypal responsibility to notify merchant each month if the action is still valid (credit enough, not unsubscribed). The IPN is the mechanism that allows the merchant implements this kind of service.